# Prolog - relation that counts number of generations

Tags: prolog

I need to create the relation "generation" in Prolog that counts how many generations there are between 2 people.

for example - if : father(a,b) and father(b,c) then there are 2 generations between a and c.

(father(a,b) = a is father of b, mother(a,b)=a is mother of b)

So generation(a,c,N) will return 2.

```
generation (X,Y,N1):- father(Z,Y), generation(Z,Y,N2), N1 is N2+1.
generation (X,Y,N1):- mother(Z,Y), generation(Z,Y,N2), N1 is N2+1.
```

is that correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need a rule for the direct relation:

```
generation(X, Y, 1):- father(X, Y), !.
generation(X, Y, 1):- mother(X, Y), !.
```

The other rule should be corrected to:

```
generation(X, Y, N1):- father(X, Z), generation(Z, Y, N2), N1 is N2+1.
generation(X, Y, N1):- mother(X, Z), generation(Z, Y, N2), N1 is N2+1.
```